# How to get users to set ACLs on directories they don't own?

Tags: scripting, acl, setuid

I have a set of storage directories on Linux machines, all 770/root:root (perms/owner:group), for which I use ACLs to manage users access. (I am unable to use unix groups as the directories are shared across a network, where groups are managed via LDAP for which I'm not an admin).

For each directory, one user has full rwx access via ACLs, and all others have rx access via ACLs.

Currently, I have to manually respond to requests to add/remove users, and I'd like this ability to be passed onto the 'rwx' users for the directories they own (because I'm a lazy sysadmin, naturally).

The best solution I can think of is to create a script/program with root setuid that checks for the 'rwx' ACL status of the calling user on the given directory, and allows them to add/remove 'rx' ACL users, as in:

```
$ modify_acls.sh [--remove] [--add] <my_directory> <other_user>
```

Is there an easier way of doing it, or will the solution above not work for any reason?

Comment: "… or will the above not work for any reason?" It actually probably won't, as setuid shell scripts tend to be disabled

Comment: Scripting it sounds like the best way to go, querying getfacl and using setfacl.

Comment: Instead of a setuid shell script, consider enabling a specific script with `sudo`.

Comment: @dirkt - that's not an option. One of the assumptions in the original question is that the change is made by a user without sudo privileges, otherwise you could just use setfacl directly, and there would be no issue to discuss.

Comment: @einonm: `sudo` isn't restricted to "allow someone to execute something as root", even though it's used most often this way, you can easily configure "user A, B and C are allowed to execute only this particular script as root" in `sudoers`. See `man sudoers` for details.

Comment: And I wouldn't recommend to allow use `setfacl` as root directly, because they can then easily do some stuff you don't want them to.

Comment: @dirkt Ok, yes you could do that..but is there an advantage over using a setuid executable, and is it potentially less secure given that setuid is not recommended for scripts?

Comment: If at all possible, I'd suggest changing the owner of the whole directory tree to something other than `root`, some user account dedicated to just that. That would protect the rest of the system from issues if someone happens to find a bug in the script you make.

Comment: Are the LDAP admins totally non-responsive?  The best solution here is to put users in proper groups instead of trying to kludge some workaround that has the potential to have serious security issues.

Comment: @ilkkachu Great idea, but unfortunately creating organisation-wide 'fake' users for such a purpose is not possible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - in our LDAP system, there aren't enough groups available to be allocated for our needs. Could you be more specific on these 'security issues'?

Comment: @einonm *in our LDAP system, there aren't enough groups available to be allocated for our needs.* Create new ones?  Others have already commented and also answered on the problems with implementing setuid scripts and sudo.  Any time you give a user permission to do things as someone else, there are potential security issues that have to be identified and then addressed.  If you miss anything, security is compromised.  And if the user you're giving rights to is root, that usually means everything accessible is compromised.

Comment: @einonm, that's the point where you go to your boss and say "I can either do these updates manually, which eats into my work hours and slows down the users; or we can create a tool for this, but it leaves a chance that someone can crack the whole file server; or, the LDAP admins could add one account into the directory..." -- I mean, isn't that what LDAP is for, having organization-wide accounts in only one place...

Comment: @ilkkachu - By groups, I really meant GIDs. This is a large university, and central IT are slow compared to our immediate needs - I would appreciate it if the discussion was held on technical points, not organisational ones. If you could point out what chance a setuid program that has one getfacl and one setfacl call in it is insecure, then I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @einonm, code carefully, sanitize your input, clean the environment (and/or don't call external programs). It's not like a usual system wouldn't have setuid executables anyway. Though doing that is a bit more work than I'd care to do for an SE answer... Anyway, my main point was just in avoiding root if you can, if just because _I'm_ paranoid. In this case, I don't think capabilities would help much since `CAP_FOWNER` is probably all-powerful anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a setuid shell script, consider enabling a specific script with `sudo`.

Even though it's used most often this way, `sudo` isn't restricted to "allow someone to execute any program as root". You can easily configure "user A, B and C are allowed to execute only this particular script as root" in `/etc/sudoers`. See `man sudoers` for details.

There isn't really an advantage of using `sudo` instead of a setuid script, except that on systems where setuid scripts are completely disabled for security reasons, the second alternative just won't work at all. You still could write a custom setuid binary, but inserting a line into `sudoers` is simpler, quicker and easier to change later on when you want to add or remove users.

Comment: `sudo` _does_ have the advantage that it sanitizes the environment by default, and the feature can be configured if some envvars need to be passed through. That's especially important with shell scripts (as opposed to binary executables), since a script is likely to run other applications that may change behaviour based on envvars.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell script will probably not work as setuid shell scripts are typically not supported on Linux.

A workaround would be to write a small executable In C to provide the required functionality and setuid root this executable.